# Having trouble adding jquery to charisma

Tags: jquery, charisma

I am trying to add some jquery to this [Charisma](http://usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template) admin panel and have been having nothing but trouble. I am trying to add it to the charisma.js file. This is what I am adding

```
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".checkbox").click(function(){

        if($(".checkbox").length == $(".checkbox:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
```

I have tried this code wrapped in the anonymous `$(function(){` as well as without, and I have inserted it into both `$(document).ready(function(){` and `docReady()` as well as in the `head` of my code but I am not really "trained" on jquery so I am a bit lost as to what I am doing wrong. My `class` and `div` tags are correct for the code, as I have checked them several times for misspellings. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there a better "check" all code I can use here, or am I just putting this all in the wrong place?

UPDATE: I think the actual code may be working, I cannot tell, after I click the select all box it seems that I have to click the other boxes 3 times to get the check mark back into the box, so it seems like it is having trouble actually showing that the box is marked. This may be a problem with styling, but I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meet the same problem as you do. My solution is like this:

find the line "

```
$("input:checkbox,input:radio, input:file").not('[data-no-uniform="true"],#uniform-is-ajax').uniform();"
```

then,remove the `input:checkbox,` then the checkbox in your project will not display in the charisma way.Now you can use `$(this).prop("checked","checked");` to make the checkbox change.